# Cannot open .dot file gvEdit

Tags: graphviz, dot

I cannot open the attached dot file in gvEdit. 
I tried to convert it to png file

```
dot -Tpng final.dot > finalgraph.png
```

it gives me the following problem:

```
dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.311296 to fit
dot: failure to create cairo surface: out of memory
```

My purpose is only to view the dot file, how should I resolve it?

The dot file is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt2q653x2x9jjbj/final.dot?dl=0

Comment: I get an invalid file format when I try to download. Anyway, try `dot -T png -o finalgraph.png final.dot `

Comment: @vaettchen, still can not work, the error message is :"dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.311296 to fit
dot: failure to create cairo surface: out of memory "

Comment: @vaettchen I try downloding the file on my computer, no problem at all, I tried on Windows 7.

Comment: I managed to download and tried but same result here on Linux. I guess the graph really is just too large. As a matter of interest - how did you generate this?

Comment: Your graph is huge, maybe you should render the subgraphs individually. Rendering to vector graphics (SVG) works.